# Simular um click , como compartilhar um link para o Google+ sem click

Tags: javascript, libcurl, phantomjs

Meu desafio é fazer um compartilhamento do meu site para o Google+ sem cliques.

Eu possuo uma conta no google `eu@gmail.com`, criei um perfil no `G+`.

A ideia é através do `localhost` criar um script onde ao ser acessado ele realizará a tarefa de compartilhar um link no stream do `G+`.

Bom nas pequisas que realizei, no G+ existem vários tipos de perfis:

Perfil comum de uma pessoa

Uma comunidade

E uma página

Na documentação das APis do [Explorer](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/) vemos 2 APIs distintas para o `G+`:

E na tabela de comparação é dito:

G+ API "Write posts to the stream" NO

G+ Domains API "Yes, restricted to the domain."

Eu não consegui entender o funcionamento dessa API "Domains"

Por esse motivo e por ver várias questões sobre isso dizendo que não há uma API pública para postar automaticamente no stream do `G+` é que eu desisti de usar a API.

Então estou tentando usar o compartilhamento e simular os cliques de confirmação para compartilhar um link automaticamente do meu site para o `G+`, a partir deste código:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Teste share G+</title>
    </head>
    <body onload="alert('hiii');document.getElementById('share_g').click();">
        <a href="https://plus.google.com/share?url=http://www.example.com" id="share_g" onclick="javascript:window.open(this.href,
  '', 'menubar=no,toolbar=no,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes,height=600,width=600');document.querySelector('span.RveJvd snByac').click(); return false;"><img
  src="https://www.gstatic.com/images/icons/gplus-64.png" alt="Share on Google+"/></a>

    </body>
</html>
```

Entretanto é necessário clicar no botão `POSTAR` para realizar a operação, existe alguma forma de simular esse click. com javascript ou phantomjs?

Qualquer outra solução é bem vinda.

Comment: Você consegue simular com jQuery $("elemento").click(); e com javascript: document.getElementById('elemento').click(); mas por padrão a simulação só funciona com algum evento do usuário, não se pode fazer a simulação sozinha.

Comment: Você ta tentando através da página X disparar um evento click em uma janela Y que foi aberta por um evento click em X?

Comment: @AnthraxisBR nem sei mais o que estou tentando,,, Eu preciso compartiilhar um link to meu site para o `G+` sem nenhum clique...

Comment: @MagicHat Acho que assim não tem como não, porque você ia ter que disparar um evento em uma janela através de outra, acho que colocar um iframe com o link do g+, preencher o iframe e triggerar o click da mais certo, da pra fazer tudo hidden.

Comment: Ao pressionar o link, uma nova janela se abre para o compartilhamento. Você deseja que o botão "Postar" seja clicado automaticamente? Mesmo que isso seja possível, isso não iria compartilhar o link toda vez que a página fosse carregada?

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss No momento o desafio é compartilhar do site pro G+ sem clique, se for possível (tenho certeza que é) , aí dá pra tomar algumas medidas para que ocorra só quando for necessário.

Answer (score -2):

Use algo parecido com isso:

```
document.getElementById('elementID').click();
```

[Suportado](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/click) inclusive no IE

Com jquery você pode fazer assim:

```
$("#mytest1").click();
```

Comment: Obrigado pela atenção, isso só funciona no mesmo domínio, que não é o caso.

Comment: Inclusive esse código já está presente no evento `onload` do `body` na pergunta, então seria fundamental explicar porque o código da pergunta não funcionou, se esta fosse a solução.